# When to protect?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

I'm just curious as to have more details as to when to protect. I seem to be on the site in a very slow time in the mornings.

If I see an answer to old question from a very new user that does seem to have problems is it still worth protecting? I don't know if protecting old questions is something I should do.

What about a question that has several poorly received answers from new user but does not seem to be too hot? Still Worth a protect then?

I don't want to abuse my new found privilege.

---

EDIT [Aug 24, 2021]: Just bumping this question to see if community standards have changed since it was first asked Feb 5, 2016.

Comment: "an answer to old question from a very new user that does seem to have problems" I don't fully understand this. Do you mean a new user posting a question as an answer? We flag such answers for deletion, and also ask the user to post their question separately, a standard procedure, at least as of today.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Old questions being bumped to the front page by new non-answers tend to get a quick volley of more non-answers from new users, and protection is a good way to prevent it.

In the case of something older that slipped through and isn't currently active, deleting those non-answers will usually auto-protect the question.  So you can just flag them.

Answer (score 3):

I usually protect a question when I see that it has received quite a few low quality and non answers.

If it is just a low quality answer or non answer at a question, I don't think I'd protect the question. It might not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the goal is to answer the question. A good question is formulated in a way that another person with the same question or problem is likely to find it. Then a late answer can be useful. If it seems that a question needs to be protected from further answers it *may* mean that it wasn't a good question in the first place.

I understand that I didn't answer this question directly, but to me it seems that it belongs to a broader topic.

Comment: The problem isn't late answers. The problem is the low-quality answers by low-reputation users (often non-registered users or trolls) tend to proliferate on occasion for particular questions. Those relatively rare cases are what protection is for.

Comment: @Aaron To me it seems we have efficient methods to identify, review and delete such answers. Also, maybe I'm wrong, but it doesn't seem to me to happen particularly often? In comparison to e.g. poorly asked questions.